# How to Detect If User is Traveling on a Particular Road in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Are there any Frameworks/APIs to see if the user is traveling on a particular road (whose coordinates are known) in the background?

My usecase is this. When a user is traveling in a particular road, I want to send him some custom notifications.

Comment: Does your app support GPS?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is CLRegion. A CLRegion is a circular geofence you create, and ask the system to monitor for you. The system will wake up your app and send it a messages when the user enters the region.

I don't know of a way to create a region that is a polyline however.

For short roads you could set up a series of regions. However, I believe there is a pretty small limit on the total number of active regions (The limit is 20 for beacon regions, and it might be the same for "regular" CLRegions. I don't remember off the top of my head.)